# Boostrap Datepicker performance issue on large number of date input items

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I need to initialize large number of dynamically created `datepicker` input in UI but I only got bad performance and even crashing of browsers. I dynamically create more than 10 input field (10 to 100), and after that I call initialization of plugin. In that moment everything start lagging and even crashing.

I'm using this bootstrap plugin [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)
Does anybody have some idea how to make this to work fine. Maybe some idea from different approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize the element when the focus is on it:

```
$('.date-picker').focusin(function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```